# Trying to extract first n characters before '||' symbol from mysql

Tags: mysql, regex, sql-like

Am trying to extract first 'n' characters from database before first '||' symbol can anyone give any idea of doing that.Here is table

table name->playlist

```
fact->column name
PLKIDHYYFFEF||hello||ee
KDKOIJOFRFOFRFRF||how||tt
```

I have been using to extract substring

```
 "SELECT * FROM playlist WHERE playlist.fact LIKE %...%";
```

Am not able to understand what pattern should be kept

Comment: select substr(colname,'1',locate('ll',colname)) from tableName; You may try some thing like this query

Comment: when am trying to print the column name using mysqli_fetch_arry its showing error as undefined for column name(which I replaced with my column name)

Comment: Can you post the query @ Shanseti vikas

Comment: Do you expect PLKIDHYYFFEF from PLKIDHYYFFEF||hello||ee or PLKIDHYYFFEFhello?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select all characters in a string until a specific character MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42285173/select-all-characters-in-a-string-until-a-specific-character-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

If you want whatever is before '||', use `SUBSTRING_INDEX()`:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, '||', 1) FROM tbl;
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, to extract the first eleven (11) characters before `||`, you can use something like:

```
(...........)\|\|
```

(remember you have to escape a literal `|` as it represents the union of the languages in the left and right operands) These will match any group of exactly eleven (11) characters before the pattern `||` (but this can include `||` itself).  If you want this to be at the beginning of the string, you can anchor it with a `^` character.  If you want a different number of characters, just change the number of dots `.` before the right parenthesis.  The requested pattern will be in group 1 of the resulting matcher.

To get it from the first pair of `|` characters, you have to consider that the string must not have encoded inside the pattern `||`, although the language of all strings of eleven characters continues to be regular (and so, it is true that it can be represented by a regular expression) the pattern of such an expression is far too complicated to be expressed here.  If you relax your requirements to any string (of any length) that does not contain the `||` sequence, and is followed by a `||` match, you can use the following (anchoring it also to the beginning of line):

```
^(([^|]|\|[^|])*)\|\|
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/RYdcQm/1).