# Select all characters in a string until a specific character MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a record in an SQL database that looks like this:

```
'839af0d3-9301-33d0-abce-e16a673980fd', 'Aforic', '7:74324:35:4:1:1203:348:27:415:158:2:0:0:0D-5H-17M-26S', 'Tactician', ' '
```

The table is defined as follows:

```
`T1` (`player_uuid`, `player_name`, `stats`, `inventory`, `selected`)
```

How do I write a query to select only the name and the first entry from "stats". Basically, I only want to select the first entry in "stats" that is before ":". In this case, it would be 7.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index).

```
select player_name,substring_index(stats,':',1) 
from T1
```

Edit: Splitting the values between the first 3 `:` delimiters,

```
select player_name
,substring_index(stats,':',1) as col_1
,substring_index(substring_index(substring_index(stats,':',3),':',-2),':',1) as col_2
,substring_index(substring_index(stats,':',3),':',-1) as col_3
from T1
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot. 

And if I want the third entry after the first? substring_index(stats,':',3)?

Comment: you are correct..the third argument is for the *nth* occurrence in the string. so you'll get the substring upto that occurrence. read the documentation so you get a thorough understanding of how it works.

Comment: substring_index(stats,':',3) gives me "7:74324:35". Is there a way to split these values in 3 different columns? 

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: see the edit.. it is a pain to split the strings in SQL..if you have to split them on each `:` you may have to write a function.

Answer (score 2):

The alternative solution using [LEFT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_left) and [LOCATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) functions:

```
SELECT
    player_name, LEFT(stats, LOCATE(':', stats) - 1)
FROM 
    T1
```

Note:

> For functions that operate on string positions, the first position is
>   numbered **1**.

Comment: The problem is I would like to select the first 3 entries. For example, I would like to get 7 in one column, 74324 in the second, and 35 in the third. Is it possible to do this?